# I use Cordova to do APP;but it run slowly when I take photo and take video

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Then I use google ,I get this message "supportedVideoModes" this option can set video`s property;but I don`t know how to use this option and how many property of this option,can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through the documentation :

Create your first Cordova app: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

cordova-plugin-camera: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html

Comment: I had read it; but I can`t get answer。 I want to make my media.size to more small , then I  can upload it quickly. How to make the video resolution down to reduce the space?